# Should we hyperlink book/verses that direct to Bible websites?

Tags: discussion, formatting, hyperlinks

For example, which is preferable?

## 1

In [John 1:1](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/8d500f4cad20274881fa01feb4c75ae7/), it it is written,

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος

## 2

In [John 1:1](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/8d500f4cad20274881fa01feb4c75ae7/), it it is written,

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος <sup>(NA28)</sup>

## 3

In [John 1:1](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/8d500f4cad20274881fa01feb4c75ae7/), it it is written,

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος <sup>([NA28](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/8d500f4cad20274881fa01feb4c75ae7/))</sup>

## 4

In John 1:1, it it is written,

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος <sup>(NA28)</sup>

## 5

In John 1:1, it it is written,

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος <sup>([NA28](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/8d500f4cad20274881fa01feb4c75ae7/))</sup>

Comment: Preferable to what? No link? Or a different sort of link? I generally think about them as offering a convenient way for those interested to see the context (and/or either the original language or English if only one or the other is quoted), but maybe you're getting at something else?

Comment: It certainly is convenient, but there are a few issues with hyperlinks, as you know, one being broken hyperlinks. For example, BlueLetterBible (www.blueletterbible.org) changed its interface from Classic to its current interface, and the URLs changed in conjunction. I've had to go through many of my olds posts and update URLs. Should we just cite the translation/version (e.g., NASB, ESV) and/or source text (VUL, Ralfs, NA28) in superscripted parentheses and just allow the reader to use their own preferred Bible or Bible website to view them? I'm just thinking about standardization here.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Oy! What was probably simpler in the earlier genesis of this site has been bogged down by the various software versions and their adaptability to Markdown. Door #3 would be my preference-I can certainly take the time to examine your sources-using my preferred OS and references.

Comment: @Tau: I may have been editing while you were commenting. Is it the current #3 that you prefer?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Yes sir, it is.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I may make an exception if it is the DSS or other more 'exotic' references. Any 'authorial' references of course should be linked.

Comment: @Tau: What about future broken links?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 That's a Caleb or Jon question; it is certainly hard to post an answer with a broken link; how much is it the site vs the OP only they can answer.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I missed your edit-it's #4 I would prefer, for the reason previously stated.

Comment: @Tau: Your comment makes more sense now. :)

Comment: What do you think of [theses](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/810/3474)?

Comment: Thank you, @PaulVargas. Those are helpful.